# Will an 8/8 with trample die if it's blocked by 4 2/2 creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When attacking with a creature that has trample, can it die if the blockers' power succeeds or equals the attacking creatures' toughness?

Example: A 8/8 with trample attacks. 4 creatures, all 2/2, block. So all 4 creatures blocking and the attacking 8/8 with trample would die correct?

Comment: Why do you specify that the 8/8 has trample? Do you expect a different outcome than a non-trampling 8/8 being blocked by 4 2/2s?

Comment: If the 8/8 didnt have trample there would be no need to block with 4 creatures... only 1 creature and no extra damage goes to player... only the 2/2 would die... why would you use 4 creatures to block when there's no need to? I mean, unless you just want to kill off 4 of your blockers to take down 1 big creature? Which to me seems dumb... but I guess that depends on how you gear your deck too...

Comment: There are lots of cases where killing the 8/8 would be worthwhile. For instance, if the 8/8 survives, it can be used as a blocker after it untaps (or, if it has vigilance, your next turn).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will die. In general, trample only affects what happens with excess damage from the attacking side, i.e. when the attacking creature's power is higher than the total toughness of the blockers. The other way around (blockers' total power vs. attacker's toughness) is not affected.

The blocking creatures will die too, except when the attacking player makes the (usually inferior) decision to distribute more than the necessary 2 damage to some of the creatures, e.g. 4 to the first and 2 to two others.